# App Crashes because iAd Fails to Resume in Time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, iad

My app runs fine when I don't have iAds. As soon as I display an iAd the system shuts down my app because the iAd can't resume in time.

How do I resolve this?

```
Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.380 (user 0.880, system 0.500), 14% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   AppSupport                      0x0001009e CPDMMessage + 158
3   AppSupport                      0x0000f3e4 -[CPDistributedMessagingCenter _sendMessage:userInfoData:oolKey:oolData:makeServer:receiveReply:nonBlocking:error:] + 848
4   AppSupport                      0x0000ed76 -[CPDistributedMessagingCenter _sendMessage:userInfo:receiveReply:error:toTarget:selector:context:nonBlocking:] + 618
5   AppSupport                      0x0000deba -[CPDistributedMessagingCenter _sendMessage:userInfo:receiveReply:error:toTarget:selector:context:] + 58
6   AppSupport                      0x0000e08e -[CPDistributedMessagingCenter sendMessageName:userInfo:] + 34
7   iAd                             0x00012bcc -[ADSession sendMessageName:userInfo:] + 100
8   iAd                             0x00013cfe -[ADSession open] + 22
9   iAd                             0x000065c2 -[ADBannerView sessionDidBecomeAvailable:] + 38
10  iAd                             0x00014d60 -[ADSessionManager considerCreatingSessions] + 416
11  iAd                             0x00014a42 __-[ADSessionManager sessionForRecipient:]_block_invoke_1 + 34
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d597c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
13  libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d69f4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 212
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00027894 __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
17  GraphicsServices                0x000045ec GSEventRunModal + 108
18  GraphicsServices                0x00004698 GSEventRun + 56
19  UIKit                           0x0000411c -[UIApplication _run] + 396
20  UIKit                           0x00002128 UIApplicationMain + 664
21  StockTwits                      0x00002c5c main (main.m:14)
22  StockTwits                      0x00002c2c start + 32
```

Comment: I am experiencing something similar (my crash report looks almost exactly the same).

Comment: I still haven't found a solution. I have switched over to AdMob temporarily until I can figure out a way to put iAd's back in without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, it's a bug with iAds.  No confirmed work around yet.  Supposed fix in 4.2, no word if it's the 4.2 SDK that's required or if users will be required to upgrade.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/309701